# how to get list of active subscribers using pubnub

Tags: javascript, titanium, pubnub

I developed a application using `pubnub`. Here I am trying to get list of subscribers of my application connected to the network currently(be in on line). I am using titanium frame work(JavaScript). Can  any one tel me how to get this list of subscribers. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking about how to get a list of active subscribers on a PubNub channel.  This is easy to do by using the on **"connect"** Callback.  You will supply an on "connect" function to be called when a new or existing user connects.  When this occurs, you will relay this information to where it is needed on your end.  I will show you some example code for Titanium:

```
PUBNUB.subscribe({
    channel    : "hello_world",      // CONNECT TO THIS CHANNEL.
    callback   : function(message){} // RECEIVED A MESSAGE.
    connect    : function() {        // CONNECTION ESTABLISHED.
        // A new user or existing user has
        // connected.  Send details to your server.

        // ---------------------------------------
        // This is a psudo-code example function:
        // ---------------------------------------
        psudo_post_url( "http://www.mywebsite.com/pubnub-user-connected", {
            "user_id" : 123456789,
            "channel" : "hello_word"
        } );
    }
})
```

You can take advantage of this on **"connect"** callback by sending the information you need to your app servers running in the cloud with Amazon EC2, Rackspace or a dedicated colo host.

Additional resources can be found in these links:

1. https://help.pubnub.com/entries/21097426-how-do-i-list-users-connected-to-a-channel
2. https://help.pubnub.com/entries/21118418-does-pubnub-provide-web-hooks
3. https://help.pubnub.com/home

Comment: thanks from this method i got to know how many subscribers are online. But may I know how to get list of subscribers to a single channel, no matter whether they are online or offline.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PubNub Presence add-on](http://blog.pubnub.com/announcing-pubnub-channel-presence/). Specifically you want to use [`here_now` function of the PubNub Titanium SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/titanium-javascript/api-reference#here_now).

Comment: Thanks.. I got answer a long back.